# Executing Regex check against a list type variable in "when:" conditional

Tags: regex, linux, ansible, jinja2

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible at all at this point, but here it goes.

**What I'm trying to achieve?**

I'm running a files/directories permissions check through /var/log/ directory with recursion. Issue is that I want to exclude several directories from the search and all nested files in them, yet I don't want to exclude further nested directories.
e.g.:

`excluding = ['/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/','/var/log/test/']`

- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/ #excluded`
- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/log.txt #excluded`
- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/ #not excluded`
- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/log.txt #not excluded`
- `/var/log/test/ #excluded`
- `/var/log/test/log.txt #excluded`
- `/var/log/test/directory/ #not excluded`
- `/var/log/test/directory/log.txt #not excluded`

**How I'm trying to achieve the result?**

So far I'm trying to use a variable that contains directory paths that I want to exclude as list items. So my playbook looks like this (for the purpose of the example, I'm using debug instead of ansible.builtin.file module):

```
---
- name: Running playbook
  become: yes
  hosts: all
  vars:
    exclusions:['/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/','/var/log/test/']

  tasks:

    - name: Get all files and directories
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: /var/log/
        recurse: yes
        file_type: any
      register: all_files

      debug:
        var: item.path is not match('^'+exclusions|join('|'))
      with_items:
      - '{{all_files.files}}'
```

This sort of works, but with an issue that any matching item.path patterns with the "exclusion" list items are matched too loosely and results in the following:

- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/ #excluded`
- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/log.txt #excluded`
- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/ #excluded`
- `/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/log.txt #excluded`
- `/var/log/test/ #excluded`
- `/var/log/test/log.txt #excluded`
- `/var/log/test/directory/ #excluded`
- `/var/log/test/directory/log.txt #excluded`

I understand that "[^/var/log/test/](https://regex101.com/r/JeLOuQ/1)" regex expression works as intended here, so my next idea was to add additional regex tokens to the "match" filter to achieve what I need to do. So "^/var/log/test/[^/]+$" expression seems to do the job.

**The issue.**

I cannot add [^/]+$ tokens in the "match" filter.
Tried by doing this:

`var: item.path is not match('^'+exclusions|join('|')+'[^\/]+$')`

But the '[^/]+$' part is ignored, most likely due to the used `join('|')` action. I did not manage to add tokens by placing them anywhere in the "match" filter.
So my question is - is it possible to somehow construct a regex expression - ^exclusions[^/]+$ that would go over the list of saved patterns?

**Sidenote**

Placing the required regex token in list variable items does the job done, but the implementation of what I'm trying to do requires to have a simple variable list (paths of directories without any additional characters):

```
---
- name: Running playbook
  become: yes
  hosts: all
  vars:
    exclusions_regex:['/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/[^\/]+$','/var/log/test/[^\/]+$']

  tasks:

    - name: Get all files and directories
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: /var/log/
        recurse: yes
        file_type: any
      register: all_files

      debug:
        var: item.path is not match('^'+exclusions_regex|join('|'))
      with_items:
      - '{{all_files.files}}'
```

So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you finally just like to "Make sure that directories under `/var/log/*` have certain permissions"?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a small error in the construction of your regex expression.

Your condition should be as follows:

```
item.path is not match('^(' ~ exclusions|join('|') ~ ')[^/]*$')
```

The regex expression looks like: `^(/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/|/var/log/test/)[^/]*$`

- `^` defines that the search starts with the first character
- with `(` and `)` a group is formed for the prefixes
- `|` separates the prefixes as *or* operation
- `[^/]*` provides a matching after the prefix, if no or any character follow, which are not `/`
- `$` defines that is searched up to the last character

*Tip:* In most cases where you want to have a string as result it is better to work with the operator `~` for string concatenation instead of the operator `+`. In some cases it makes no difference, but then `~` is not wrong either. The string concatenation operator ensures that other data types such as integers are automatically converted into a string.

#### Example Tasks

```yaml
- name: Print out all path with matched bool
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.path }} -- matched? {{ valid }}"
  vars:
    valid: "{{ item.path is not match('^(' ~ exclusions|join('|') ~ ')[^/]*$') }}"
  with_items: "{{ all_files.files }}"
```

```
TASK [Print out all path with matched bool] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/ -- matched? False"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/log.txt'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/log.txt -- matched? False"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/ -- matched? True"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/log.txt'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/log.txt -- matched? True"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/test/ -- matched? False"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/log.txt'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/test/log.txt -- matched? False"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/directory/'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/test/directory/ -- matched? True"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/directory/log.txt'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/test/directory/log.txt -- matched? True"
}
```

```yaml
- name: Print out matched paths only
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.path }}"
  when: item.path is not match('^(' ~ exclusions|join('|') ~ ')[^/]*$')
  with_items: "{{ all_files.files }}"
```

```
TASK [Print out matched paths only] ****************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/log.txt'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/log.txt'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/directory/log.txt"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/'})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/log.txt'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/directory/'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/test/directory/"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/log/test/directory/log.txt'}) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/test/directory/log.txt"
}
```

#### Tip

Don't just output the final result via `debug`, but also parts of it, like the regex expression alone, without it already being evaluated by `match()`, then you can see more easily what's going on.

Your two expressions look like this:

- `{{ '^'+exclusions|join('|') }}`
  Produces: `^/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/|/var/log/test/`
- `{{ '^'+exclusions|join('|')+'[^\/]+$' }}`
  Produces: `^/var/log/microsoft/mdatp/rotated/|/var/log/test/[^/]+$`

From this you can already see that something is not quite right yet.